# How to create random color that must be unique for every unique data in column?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

So, we have some data here:

```
    df1 <- read.table(text = "
      Client
        A
        A
        B
        C
        B
        D
        A
        C
    ", header = TRUE)
```

Also i found a library named *randomcoloR*:

```
install.packages("randomcoloR")
library(randomcoloR)
[1] "#dd7e1f"
```

The question is how to get unique color for every unique client? Something like that:

```
Client  Color
A    #dd7e1f
A    #dd7e1f
B    #29cebb
C    #17b5a0
B    #29cebb
D    #2a5ca3
A    #dd7e1f
C    #17b5a0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this would to the job:

```
library(randomcoloR)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Client) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Color = randomcoloR::randomColor()) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

By chance you could possibly get the same random color but you can verify that at the end and run it again until you have what you need.

```
# number of distinc clients
nr_Clients <- df1_c %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(Client) %>% 
  nrow()
# number of discint colors
nr_COLORS <- df1_c %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(Color) %>% 
  nrow()

# check if there are as many colors as clients (if true you are fine if not run the block again)
nr_clients == nr_COLORS
```

Also there could be situations where the colors are very similar (not to say they look the same) though they have a slightly different code

Comment: Also i see that there is an argument we may pass to the `randomColor()` as `count number of colors (>= 1)` so it is posible to count quantity of unique clients and then pass it as a parametr to the function like: `randomColor(4)`